# How do I use the text value into a function?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import psutil

master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()

def callback():
    print(e.get())  # This is the text you may want to use later

b = Button(master, text="OK", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()

def count(n):
    while n > 0:
        print(n)
        time.sleep(1)
        n = n - 1

count(e.get())
```

I am trying to set a timer from the number (text) which is given as input by the user in the text field. But everytime I run the code, I keep getting this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Internshala_dreambig/src/game.py", line 32, in <module>
    count(e.get())
  File "C:\Users\Abhishek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2682, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Move that `mainloop()` to the end of file.

Comment: Tried that, shows this error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

Comment: `time.sleep` will block the main thread of tkinter. You should look up how to use `root.after` to deal with things like this.

Comment: Well, that's called *programming*, now you're getting closer to a solution. Change that `count(e.get())` to `count(int(e.get()))`. And then ask for more or debug it by yourself...

Comment: @ipaleka lol, you thought I didn't try that, it now shows`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error

Comment: You don't even allow your entry to be entered by a user, that's the real problem here. And about that error, you should set the default value different from an empty string, like `e.insert(0, "1")`.

Comment: Your `count` function should be started by a button instead. There is nothing in your entry widget when you start `count` right away.

Comment: instead of `while` loop and `sleep()` better use `after(1000, callback)` inside `callback` to run it every 1000ms (1). `sleep()` will block `mainloop()` which makes all jon in GUI - ie. it redraw widgets - so window will freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers, I am new to GUI programming using python, so I apologize for asking these kind of silly questions.

After struggling for a long time, I've finally found out a working solution. (Although its strange, that it doesn't show any **ValueError** while converting the input text to `int` like before).

Here is the reformatted code:

```
def count(n):
   while n > 0:
     print(n)
     time.sleep(1)
     n = n - 1
   if n == 0:
     #do something


master = Tk()
e = Entry(master)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()


def callback():
    print(e.get())
    count(int(e.get()))


b = Button(master, text="OK", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while` loop and sleep better use `root.after(1000, update_timer)` to execute function `update_timer` every 1000ms (1s). This function will update value and update text in `Label`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def start():
    global count

    count = entry.get()

    try:
        count = int(count)
        update_timer()
    except:
        label['text'] = 'wrong value'

def update_timer():
    global count

    if count >= 0:
        label['text'] = str(count)
        count -= 1
        root.after(1000, update_timer)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
entry.focus_set()

button = tk.Button(root, text="START", command=start)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```